# PG-Strom and spatial queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to start using the GPU on my server in my PostgreSQL queries. I cannot find much information about the use of PG-Strom for spatial queries. The most I have found is that it may be coming in PostgreSQL 9.6. We are beyond that now. So? What's happening with this? Where are the resources?

http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2015/presentation/S5276-Kohei-KaiGai.pdf

https://github.com/heterodb/pg-strom

I am working with PostgreSQL 12.1, PostGIS 3 with a VOLTA Tesla V100 16GB

Comment: Found that PG11 is the latest (test) version https://heterodb.github.io/swdc/ (pg_strom-PG11-test-2.2-2.el7.x86_64.rpm)

Comment: No updates for a while contact is available via https://github.com/heterodb/pg-strom/wiki/003:-Development-Roadmap

Comment: I was afraid of that... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being in contact with the developers of Pg-Strom, we are now aware that spatial queries are not currently supported by Pg-Strom, nor is there a plan to do so in the near future without financial investment.

"Right now, we have no special activities to support PostGIS functions, due to non-technical reasons. We have not met a prospective user who agree to purchase our
enterprise software subscription with support of the spatial functions in the past, even though some folks are interested in the feature.

From the standpoint of technology, yes, here is no reason why we cannot implement GPU-executable version of these PostGIS functions...

If you can give us a commitment of the purchase and the target workloads (data & queries) to be accelerated in the 1st version, we can move forward the related features." --KaiGai Kohei